# Troubleshooting "require_once(../bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: symfony-2.1

I am trying to redeploy a Symfony 2.1x project I have been working on and `app_dev.php` is failing because it can't find `app/bootstrap.php.cache`. This file is omitted from the project's git repository because I used Symfony2's recommend `.gitignore` file:

```
# .gitignore
/app/bootstrap*
```

Am I correct in thinking that `app/bootstrap.php.cache` is generated during the `$ php composer.phar install` process? If this is the case then I will include for you my `composer.json`:

```
// composer.json
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "dev-master",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "ddeboer/guzzle-bundle": "dev-master",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "version": "master",
                "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

How can I generate `bootstrap.php.cache`?

Comment: First of all you should check if you have right permissions for you files and folders.

Comment: The cache file ships with symfony.  Have you checked your app directory?  Did you perhaps delete it?  Are the paths in app_dev.php pointing to the correct directory?  Does app/console work?

Comment: I did delete the contents of the directory and then attempted to redeploy the project from its git repository back into it. If `bootstrap.php.cache` is not meant to be in the repo how does it get added back to a project after deployment from git? I still assume it's done in the composer installation process but if someone knows better please enlighten me.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Just go to your project and generate it with composer like

```
php /path/to/composer/composer.phar install
```

Comment: Just wait a minute before running this command: Do you really want to *update* your vendors? `composer.phar install` command will create the missing bootstrap.php.cache file you're looking for and won't modify your vendors versions.

Comment: You probably want `composer update --lock` since it does trigger the post-step, but does NOT actually update any dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

Just run the following command.

```
php composer.phar install
```

**Source:** http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/performance.html#use-bootstrap-files

Answer (score 4):

You have duplicated `post-install-cmd` and `post-updated-cmd` while you should have added MopaBootstrapBundle scripts to existing keys. Try the following composer.json and re-run `php composer.phar install`

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "dev-master",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "ddeboer/guzzle-bundle": "dev-master",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "version": "master",
                "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Comment: This was definitely part of the problem and I thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my composer version was 2.x and the required version was 1.x
so, first i needed to downgrade to version 1 and then i run composer install

```
sudo composer self-update --1 && composer install -v --prefer-dist
```