# How to run a symfony2 project from existing code on xampp

Tags: php, symfony, xampp

I have a symfony2 project. I need to run it on my local environment using xampp. I placed the existing code in xampp but when i go to `localhost/myproject`, it simple list the directories and files there.
I also installed `composer` in that directory

**EDIT**
When I move to `web` directory, it gives me following error

```
Warning: require_once(G:\xampp\htdocs\m\developer\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\m\developer\web\app_dev.php on line 23

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'G:\xampp\htdocs\m\developer\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in G:\xampp\htdocs\m\developer\web\app_dev.php on line 23
```

Comment: Symfony's web root dir is located unde the "web" directory. It's also recommanded that you use a vhost file.

Comment: And this file does exists actually?

Comment: yeah, it does not exist. If i am getting an existing code, should this file be included in the project?

Comment: So i agree with @Veve comment. Try to reinstall your vendors : remove `vendor` and `composer.lock` then run `composer install`, and try again...

Comment: removed `composer.lock` and ran the command, still getting the error `could not open composer.phar`

Comment: Well you clearly do not have `composer` installed. https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem between a project made in a linux environment, not functionning in a windows one.
You could make a `php composer.phar install` in your project directory, it should resolve your issue.

If there are troubles, you may want to get a fresh start with [a clean `composer.json`](http://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json) , remove `composer.lock` and the `vendor` forlder, then add the bundles you need in it.

Comment: `composer.json` file is not there :(

Comment: Have you a composer.json file in your project folder?

Comment: i dont have this file on root, I have this file in subfolder, and when i do the command in subfolder, it gives me `could not open input file` error

Comment: This file must be in your main project folder to work.

Comment: copied this file in my main folder, ran the command and now I am getting `Yor requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages` 5 reasons under that :(

Comment: You may want to get a fresh start with a clean composer.json (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json) then add the bundles you need in it.

Comment: you mean to place this file in my directory and run the commands?

Comment: Yes, see the edit of my answer, and the comments from Koalabaerchen.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is if you go to `localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php`

The proper way would be by configuring a virtual host.
This question might help you with it [Symfony 2 on virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962054/symfony-2-on-virtual-hosts)

**EDIT to your EDIT**

[Troubleshooting "require_once(../bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958091/troubleshooting-require-once-bootstrap-php-cache-failed-to-open-stream-no)

Comment: it gives me error on console `could not open input file composer.json`

Comment: OK, I think you have to reinstall it. There is something broken. Try the initial installation as mentioned by @Veve or at http://symfony.com/download

Comment: I installed a fresh copy of symfony with helloworld application and its working fine. I need to run existing symfony application, thats what is causign me a problem