# Twig templates will not update

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a twig template as simple as:

```
{# Digital Assets #}
<li class="digAssets" {{ ('digital_assets' == category) ? 'current' }}">
    <a href="{{ path('digital_assets') }}">Digital Assets</a>
</li>
```

But when I try to change something as simple as

```
<a href="{{ path('digital_assets') }}">Digital Assets</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ path('digital_assets') }}">Analog Assets</a>
```

it does not update. I've tried putting

```
cache: false
auto_reload: true
```

into both app/config/config.yml, config_dev.yml, and config_prod.yml with no success.

Comment: try to remove the twig cache

Comment: By the way, you seem to have an extra quote after digAssets <li class="digAssets" {{ ('digital_assets' == category) ? 'current' }}">

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this through app.php (prod), you may need to run:

Symfony 2:
`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Symfony 3:
`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

I haven't played around with the cache: false at all.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error saying 'require_once((DIR)/symfony/bin/../var/bootstrap.php.cache):failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...'
When I look for the file manually in the directory, it's not there.

Comment: I think a `composer update` should fix that?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958091/troubleshooting-require-once-bootstrap-php-cache-failed-to-open-stream-no